# UIScrollView + UITextView Resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

So I have two elements on my page. A UIScrollView which holds all the contents of the page, and a UITextView, which gets dynamically populated with text, and then resized to a specific size like so:

```
self.productDescription.text = @"Long Description here.....";
CGRect frame = self.productDescription.frame;
frame.size.height = 10;
self.productDescription.frame = frame;
```

This works as lovely as one could hope- But, as soon as you scroll the UIScrollView this is embedded in, the textview reverts to it's original size.

Comment: What is your textview original height? and content size of your scroll view?

Comment: Have you implemented any _delegate_ methods for the `scrollView` ? If so, then have you set the frame for your `textView` in any of these methods ?

Comment: @jai 126px. I set the scroll view to some huge number (I think like 1500 or something) to make sure it doesn't affect it.

Comment: @GoGreen Nope. Should I be?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Did you notice the line `frame.size.height = 10;`. I think you are resetting the _height_ to always be of the value `10`. Shouldn't it be `frame.size.height += 10;` ?

Comment: Where do change the height of your text view viewdidload? or some where else?

Comment: @GoGreen The 10 pixels is intentional. In the actual release, the number is going to be calculated in realtime (One of those automatically growing text fields), but for now, I want to get it to resize and not revert.

Comment: @jai In a separate event, which is fired after the server returns the json values that I use to populate the page.

Comment: try updating the UI after the _height_ is changed. Use: `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantPast]];`

Comment: @GoGreen Still responds the same way when I scroll.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. What did you conclude?

Comment: @JustinDamnMoore I wasn't ever able to figure it out, sorry :(